# Intermittent slow ActiveRecord / MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hope someone here can give me some pointers.  We have a Rails app, scaled horizontally across 5 ruby instances, pointing to a single MySQL database.  We have POST requests that are made to this app that return generally in the 600ms range.  Occasionally, however, these requests run for incredibly long times, like 50s+.  It doesn't look like anything out of the ordinary is happening in the ruby code.  Does this mean we need to scale our MySQL instances?  To the extent of my knowledge we aren't hitting it that hard, certainly not 20k+ requests a second which I think is what it can handle.  Would appreciate any pointers to where to start looking.  We've started profiling our app with NewRelic as well.

```
Started POST "/api/something" for *** at 2012-07-16 19:00:19 +0000
  Processing by SomethingController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {}
Completed 200 OK in 59542ms (Views: 1.8ms | ActiveRecord: 59265.2ms)
```

Comment: Do you have acess to a mysql terminal? can you run `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` when there is a slow request, to see if and what that locks the database

Answer (score 0):

1.) Have a look at the `params` Hash that was send before the app generated that 59s database query. Compare it to the other params and look for differences that might cause trouble.

2.) start the `mysqld` with the `--log=/path/to/log.log` option to log all queries that are handled by the server and have a look at the query thats taking such a long time.

3.) Check if all foreign keys have an index. Rails doesnt add an index to foreign key columns by default. This is a generally problem that some rails developers just ignore. When you have some foreign keys without index add an index to them by a migration.